# Search macro from sheet 1 and copy to sheet 2

Tags: excel, search

I have in 1 sheet all names of our country cities together with their zip codes e.g.

```
A1=1000 A2=Brussels
B1=2000 B2=Antwerpen
```

In the second sheet I only have a part of those cities but grouped by province.

How to make a macro to look up the zip code in `A` and copy it next to those names in second sheet?

Comment: can you show sample data? i think it is possible with a formula.

Answer (score 0):

As i've commented, this is how to do it with formula:

Suppose you have a data like this in `Sheet1`:

[image: Sheet1]

Use the following formula in `Sheet2`:
Enter it in `B2`.

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet1!$B$2:$B$11,MATCH(1,IF(ISERROR(SEARCH(Sheet1!$A$2:$A$11,A2)),0,1),0),1),"City not in list")
```

**Important:** Should be entered as `Array Formula` by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>

Which should look like this:

[image: Sheet2]

Now, you have the `Zip Code` of the corresponding addresses in `Sheet2`.
Cell addressed solely based on my dummy data.
Change it to suit your needs if you are open to `Formula`.
Hope this somehow help you.

Comment: I tried to enter it like you showed on those 2 pics , with ctrl+shift+enter and i get an formula error.

Comment: but do we have the same data structure? if you can give me sample data that would be great

Comment: which sheet is that? is that the one with the address? I thought you have 2 sheets? Which instruction above is unclear? :)

Comment: This is second sheet , but wait , i discovered something else , i need to translate the iferror match into dutch commands. let me try this first , ill be back to you

Comment: Ok np. i'll be right here :D Also, you need to adjust the target cells to match the layout of your data. What shown above is just my assumption on how your data looks like.

Comment: I keep getting an error on MATCH , see link [link]http://nl.tinypic.com/r/30tnq1d/5

Comment: you entered it using `Ctrl` + `Shift` + `Enter`? I wonder why its happening. Also, is your data structured the same as my example?

Comment: Yes i made an same structure of data  , sheet 1 having the city names and on right side the zipcodes.In sheet 2 i have only the names.In B2 i paste that line of you and ctrl+shift+enter. I dont get those {}.but i get this error that formula is wrong.Thanks for helping me out.I also took an english version of excel , same thing.

Comment: excel version? 2003? 2007? 2010?. `IFERROR` is not available in 2003. but judging from your screen shots, it's not 2003.

Comment: excel 2007 , english version

Comment: Ok, you have to show sample data, sheet1 and sheet2. Better if you can upload a sample wb. Without it im like guessing whats wrong.

Comment: here is an sample data [link]https://www.dropbox.com/s/w6glw1w723eobux/sampledata.xlsx

Comment: ok, it's working on mine. i've uploaded my file as well. see [HERE](http://wikisend.com/download/584196/sample.xlsx)

Comment: Yes i saw , but is it accurate? please go in sheet 2 and change A1 in to city maasmechelen , zipcode 3665 will be found but this incorrect , coz it need to be 3630.

Comment: yeah, problem is you have `As` City. which can be found inside Ma `as` mechelen. So it returns the first found match.

Comment: Is it not possible to have an entire word match? or in case of something like As it will tell me also an count of found matches? them i can control it manual.thnx for helping me so far